# Hindi display of words such as "pra" "gra"

Tags: keyboard, fonts, unicode

Words such as (pran) -  प्राण, (grameen) - ग्रामीण are incorrect when compared with traditional hindi writing. The first alphabet should have a small forward slash joined towards the bottom to represent र instead of having the alphabet र being explicitly displayed. Can anyone explain why this has been done?

Comment: +1 Very good question **:-)** . I know you want to write [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MCTgC.png) instead of संक्रांति

Comment: This is font dependent. See this : [proper spellings when used kinnari bold font](http://i.stack.imgur.com/n7wUY.png)

Comment: @user68186, So it is a font issue?

Comment: Please share the  keyboard and font name that you use. I am using Hindi (Wx) keyboard. Have tried both FreeSans and KInnari font in LibreOffice but am still getting incorrectly rendered word. @Serverus Tux.

Comment: Installing Hindi, along with setting CTL to Hindi in LibreOffice has solved the problem.

Comment: After adding Hindi language support, even chrome is correctly displaying the words

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Step 1 is for Ubuntu 16.04 and above

**Step 1: Install Language Support**

Go to System Settings...> Language Support > Install Languages and  install Hindi (or any other Indian language).

**Step 2: Install Keyboard Layout**

Go to System Settings... > Keyboard > Text Entry (at the very bottom left) > The `+` sign at the bottom left and add the keyboard layout of your choice, such as Hindi (Wx).

**Step 3: Enable Complex Text Layout in LibreOffice**

Go to Tools menu> Language > All Text > More.

Look for Complex Text Layout (CTL) and choose your language (Hindi). It should look something like this:

[image]

You may want to un-check the box "for current document only" at the bottom.

I have Hindi (Wx) working in `gedit` and `LibreOffice` but on in the Ask Ubuntu Answer text box.

Hope this helps

Comment: Installing Hindi, along with setting CTL to Hindi in LibreOffice has solved the problem.

Comment: @neelanshu, would you flag this answer as accepted as it works for you. It will help others with same issue to find this solution.