# Incorrect rendering/display of Devanagari fonts in browsers: Chrome, Firefox etc

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, fonts

When I typed the title I was directed to another question "[Hindi display of words such as "pra" "gra"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786002/hindi-display-of-words-such-as-pra-gra)". My experience is somewhat different than discussed there. The display is correct in LibreOffice and Text Editor but not in browser search results page. Again if you click the link with incorrect display the actual website displays correctly. I experimented with copying the incorrectly displayed lines and pasted in text editor and it displayed correctly.
[image: as shown in this image]

This problem seems to be only in Debian/Ubuntu and distros based on them. I have tried a few other distros like Fedora, Manjaro and Solus and everything is displayed correctly in them.

Comment: What's the web browser where the font doesn't display correctly?

Comment: It is not browser specific. I have tried Firefox, Chrome and Midori and it is the same in all browsers. Thanks.

Comment: [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/855739/how-can-i-make-devanagari-fonts-render-properly-in-ubuntu-16-04/855811#855811) didn't help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make Devanagari fonts render properly in Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/855739/how-can-i-make-devanagari-fonts-render-properly-in-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: To  the close voters: This is not a duplicate but an issue with default fonts in the browser.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## This is an issue with the default fonts used by the browsers

See [How do I enable writing in Indian languages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165637/how-do-i-enable-writing-in-indian-languages/165650#165650) if you have not enabled Indian language yet. This answer is for problems specific to Indian language font rendering in the browser.

For some reason Indian fonts are not rendered correctly in the browsers in Ubuntu. Changing the default fonts used by the browsers solves it. The instructions below are for Chrome. The same can be done for Firefox.

## Steps:

**First:** Open the Chrome settings and scroll down to Appearance.

**Second:** Click on Customize fonts

[image]

**Third:** Change the *Standard Font* to a font that fully supports Indian languages. Here I have chosen **Lohit Devanagari** but you can choose another one.

[image]

## The proof of the pudding...

[image]

is in eating!

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. This has solved the issue for me. I have to do this for every browser. But I expect this to work out of box which is true for Windows, Mac, iOC, Android, Fedora, Manjaro, Solus, Slacko Pup etc for all browsers. Why can't Ubuntu do this? How do we tell and request Ubuntu team to look into this? Regards.

Comment: You have to file a bug report to the Ubuntu developer team. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs for how to do that. Bug reports are off-topic here in this site.

Comment: this is also a problem on arch

Answer (score 1):

**This is happening because of fonts.**

To render any language text, font should support that text.
Default fonts of Ubuntu does not render Devanagari correctly.

In order to correctly show devanagari text, we need a font which is fully supporting devanagari.

To setup the correct font we need to do following steps.

1. Download [Noto Sans Devanagari](https://www.google.com/get/noto/#sans-deva). This package contains many fonts.
2. Open `Home` folder and check for hidden files. You can use `Ctrl + H` for the same.
3. If you cannot find `.font` folder, create one.  Extract downloaded zip file into this folder. This step will integrate all these fonts into Ubuntu. So technically you can use any of these fonts in any of the software.
4. Open settings of chrome. Search for `font`. Click on `Customize Fonts`.
5. Change `Standard Font` to `Lohit Devanagari` or any other font which renders devanagari correctly.

To render devanagari correctly in any other application, we can do the same by selecting font as `Lohit Devanagari`.