# Unicode Gujarati language word not rendering correctly in browsers

Tags: fonts, unicode

Using Google Input tools (the web-version as well as in Gmail) and in a Unicode converter online tool I am trying to get a word `જયેન્દ્ર` but somehow, *except at one place in Firefox browser (please see under Unicode Character box in attached screenshot **mozilla_3.png**)*, it is rendering incorrectly. I verified this on Firefox and Google Chrome browsers I have on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine.

**mozilla_1.png**

[image]

**mozilla_2.png**

[image]

**mozilla_3.png**

[image]

**google_chrome_1.png**

[image]

**google_chrome_2.png**

[image]

Note:

1. Both the browsers are of latest version supported on the specified version of Ubuntu.
2. As a matter of fact trying to paste that word in this post without code quotes it gets rendered incorrectly.
3. I have already made the font-settings as recommended in https://askubuntu.com/a/1008803/428475

Can anybody please let me know what could be the reason behind this behaviour and how do I fix it?

Comment: Without being able to explain the reason, I have one idea: Install the `fonts-noto-core` package and try the `Noto Sans Gujarati` font.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson `fonts-noto-core` is not available for Ubuntu 18.04 which I use on my machine. It is available for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (see [here](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-main-arm64/fonts-noto-core_20200323-1_all.deb.html)). I tried searching for the package for Ubuntu 18.04 and found https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/fonts-noto-hinted and trying to install that I see the message `fonts-noto-hinted is already the newest version (20171026-2)` but I am unable to view the `Noto Sans Gujarati` in available fonts list in Firefox settings. Only `Noto Sans Mono` is visible.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson My bad! The font `Noto Sans Gujarati` was available in the dropdown but at a level very much down which earlier I didn't navigated to. But just changing the default font didn't helped. I had to set that as the font in Sans-serif dropdown as well. And I kept the Monospace dropdown's value unchanged which was default set to `DejaVu Sans Mono`. And now the problems in reported in my question are resolved. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the suggestions in comment [Unicode Gujarati language word not rendering correctly in browsers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1387974/unicode-gujarati-language-word-not-rendering-correctly-in-browsers#comment2397189_1387974) I was able to resolve the issue.

Summarizing the steps below:

1. Install [font-noto-hinted](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/fonts-noto-hinted) (for Ubuntu 18.04; that is the version I am using)
2. For Mozilla Firefox goto its Settings -> Language and Appearance -> Fonts and Colors -> Advanced and change the value for *Serif* (aka Default font) and *Sans-serif* to **Noto Sans Gujarati**.
3. For Google Chrome go to its Settings -> Appearance - Customize Fonts and change *Standard Font* to **Noto Sans Gujarati**

Thanks.