# Problem Regarding display of Devanagari in ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, language-support, utf-8

I am able to see Hindi pretty much.
But, Issue is related to display of some particular characters, Which are not displayed by Ubuntu.
 Not displaying doesn't mean that they are displaying by box, It means it is displayed by some combination of character of Devanagari.

So, let start by the Unicode standard for displaying "Devanagari".
 All of the Hindi characters are not represented by the UTF-8. 
Instead of the some characters are displayed by the combination of some unique character.
So, Whenever that unique combination occur, It should be replaced by that particular representation.
 For reference see:

- Variant section of [Unicode : Where](https://www.unicode.org/standard/where/), also look at [Devanagari Unicode Document](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.0.0/ch09.pdf#G12284).

When i am writing Bus ki Yatra. 
I wish [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZ6ij.png) not [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuxfX.png) what ubuntu doing. See Yatra.
You can find many such example.
How to resolve such issue?

Comment: Is the problem with display or writing? Are Hindi web pages displayed correctly? Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Have you installed the required language pack? Have you installed the needed language keyboard mapping? Please edit you question above and add all the new information there.

Comment: Also see [Hindi display of words such as "pra" "gra"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786002/hindi-display-of-words-such-as-pra-gra)