# Hindi display of words such as “pra” “gra” in Kate (or other lightweight text editor)

Tags: keyboard-layout, text-editor, input-method, kate, unicode-entry

I have the following problem:

Hindi display of words such as “pra” “gra”

which has been answered for Libreoffice, in the question below:

[Hindi display of words such as "pra" "gra"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786002/hindi-display-of-words-such-as-pra-gra)

In Libreoffice, one has to tick the Complex Text Layout option, to get the “pra” “gra” ligatures to display correctly.

My question is how to get this to work in other programs, such as Kate (in KDE)?

I am writing documents in Kate in markdown in Hindi & English (Libreoffice doesn't support markdown), can this also work in Kate, or is there another lightweight editor where ligatures are displayed correctly (like in Libreoffice)?

Comment: Isn't this basically the same question as you already posted, i.e. [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1093013) which was marked as duplicate. Did you try the answer in the duplicate question? If it didn't help, can you please elaborate on how your problem differs from the problem in the duplicate question.

Comment: So i solved the problem in Libreoffice, but I don't use Libreoffice as my main editor, and although it works in Libreoffice (once the CTL option is used), i still have the same problem in Kate and other programs.

Comment: I don't talk about LibreOffice at all. I'm talking about [the duplicate of your previous question](https://askubuntu.com/q/855739).

Comment: i have solved my issue (and posted it below), sorry for the bother

Answer (score 0):

A solution i have found:

Running Kate in KDE, I had to disable the automatic spellcheck under System Settings -> Regional Settings -> Spell Check (default language Hindi) -> uncheck "Automatic spell-checking enabled by default".